# Get Year from Current Time - CesiumJS

Tags: cesium

In [Styling GeoJSON by Attributes with Cesium](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/342981) I asked about styling a GeoJSON in Cesium. Now that i have resolved that, I am trying to animate my Cesium scene. I have added a clock to my Cesium scene with the relevant range.

Here is the code :

```
var clock = new Cesium.Clock({
            startTime: Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('1979-01-01'),
            stopTime: Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2014-01-01'),
            clockRange: Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
            clockStep: Cesium.ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER,
            multiplier: 7889238, 
            shouldAnimate: true 
        });
        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
            imageryProvider: new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({assetId: 3845}),
            clockViewModel: new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock),
            shouldAnimate : true
        });
        var source1 = 'part of path';
        var source2 = 'part 2 of path';
        var year_time = 'year from current clock time';



        getLayer(year_time);

        function getLayer(year) {
            var promise = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(source1 + year + source2);
```

What I need is to get the current time value from the clock as a year and pass that to a function that creates and styles the GeoJSON.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

UPDATE:

I have been able to find a way to get the year as the time changes but for some reason when i try to pass it along to the getLayer function it get an error.
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
Here is my updated code sample:

```
            var clock = new Cesium.Clock({
            startTime: Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('1979-01-01'),

            currentTime: Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('1979-01-01'),

            stopTime: Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2014-01-01'),
            clockRange: Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP,
            clockStep: Cesium.ClockStep.SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER,

            multiplier: 15778476,

            shouldAnimate: true
        });
        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer", {
            imageryProvider: new Cesium.IonImageryProvider({assetId: 3845}),
            clockViewModel: new Cesium.ClockViewModel(clock),

            shouldAnimate: true,
            skyAtmosphere: false,
            skyBox: false

        });
        viewer.camera.flyTo({
            destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-56.5, 45.45, 450000.0),
            orientation: {
                pitch: Cesium.Math.toRadians(-50.0)
            }
        });

        var source1 = 'GeoJSON path part 1';
        var source2 = 'GeoJSON path part 2';

        var year_time = '';
        viewer.clock.onTick.addEventListener(function (clock) {
            year_time = Cesium.JulianDate.toIso8601(viewer.clock.currentTime).substr(0, 4);
        });
        console.log(year_time);
        getLayer(year_time);

        function getLayer(year) {
            var promise = Cesium.GeoJsonDataSource.load(source1 + year + source2);
```

Now I think I'm getting close but I believe that I'm going to need a way to only call the layer and maybe remove the past layer. I'm pretty stuck right now so any advice would be welcome!